# How can you easily reorder columns in LINQ to SQL designer?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

When designing LINQ classes using the LINQ to SQL designer I've sometimes needed to reorder the classes for the purposes of having the resultant columns in a DataGridView appear in a different order. Unfortunately this seems to be exceedingly difficult; you need to cut and paste properties about, or delete them and re-insert them manually.

I *know* you can reorder columns fairly easily in a DataGridView, however that would result in a lot of hardcoding and I want the designer to match up to the grid.

Does anyone know of any easier way of achieving this or is cutting/pasting the only available method?

I tried manually editing the .designer.cs file, but reordering properties there doesn't appear to do anything!

**Edit:** Just to make it clear - I want to reorder what's in the LINQ to SQL designer, not what's in the table. I haven't made an error in ordering requiring a reversion to the original table layout; rather I have a table which I want to possess a different ordering in Visual Studio than in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq-to-Sql, you can have columns in the DataGridView appear different than in the original table by:

1. In your Linq query, extract the columns that you want, in the order than you want, and store them in a var. Then the autogenerate columns should show them in that order in the DataGridView
2. Use Template columns in your DataGridView
3. Do not use drag-and-drop on the Linq-to-Sql design surface to create your entities. Rather, create them by hand and associate them with the database table using table and column properties

As far as I know, there is no drag-and-drop column reorder in the designer itself

Answer (score 2):

Open the [DataClasses].dbml file in your favorite XML editor, and reorder the [Column] elements for the table.  Save, and reopen (or reload) the designer in Visual studio.  The order of the columns displayed in the designer will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the scenario where you have reordered the columns in the database, and you now want to have this new order be reflected in the designer, I think that you have to delete the table from the designer and then put it in again. Or if you use [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) to generate your Linq-to-Sql classes, rerun it on your database and use the newly generated file.

Comment: How would deleting+putting in again help me re order columns?... What's SqlMetal?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I mis-stated the question - I want to reorder the *original table layout* so it appears in a different order in the DataGridView than in the table.